# App once crashed cant be opened again in iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have created an iOS app using Xamarin Forms, due to some error the app crashed. When I open the app again ,it displays the page on which the app had previously crashed and crashes again.

I integrated HockeyApp to catch the error also but it fails to catch this particular error.

Could you please help me out with this issue?

Comment: There are no magicians here. You need to provide either exact error that is happening (you may see it in the Output window, or the exact code that is causing the crash. Other than that there are billions of ways that the app can crash and one can only guess which one is happening for you.

Comment: If you shut the phone down and start it up again (reboot it) does it continue to occur?

Comment: I'd recommend using Xamarin.Insights. Hockeyapp is awful. Spotted plenty crashes with XI before though!

Comment: @IvanIčin breakpoints for code used in the portable part of the project do not get hit. So I'm unable to find which code is causing the bug.

Usually when an ios app crashes, we can reopen a new instance of that app, but here it crashes again after opening the app

Comment: @djent_nathan you can use Debug.WriteLine() to estimate where the app crashes if you can't hit breakpoints.

Comment: @Dbl Insights is now merged with HockeyApp

Comment: I'm still using it seperately. The api of HockeyApp was trash compared to XI. But good to know i guess